# Reaktor Help for the Class Assigment

Tags: reaktor

Can anyone help me with this Reaktor Assignment please??

Assignment 1

You must choose three sounds to use for signal processing.

One should be rhythmic, 
one should be verbal and 
another should be tonal.

Using these three sounds as sources,
create six Reaktor patches that demonstrate concepts discussed in class

and

also demonstrate your exploration into creative signal routing.

You will be expected to have at least one patch that explores

"control rate modulation", 
another patch that explores 
"audio rate modulation", 
one patch that uses an "envelope follower" 
and
another that uses an "effect driven by tempo."

You are required to document each patch with a "schematic" of your signal path.

Comment: Agreeing with the other responses, why are you asking for help on something that you should love to do yourself? Do you not like your study? Or are you trolling?

Comment: What part of your assignment are you having trouble with? We're happy to answer a specific question, if you ask one.

Answer (score 4):

No-one will/should do your homework.

Read the manual and lecture notes, do the assignments that **you're** given that are part of a course that **you've** decided to take.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with 0.5piRC. If you had come here with some ideas or partly formed patches then we could have had a discussion or offered some pointers, but simply posting the task verbatim???

Don't forget that lecturers also frequent forums like this one...